# Is it possible to use tab to move between buffers whilst keeping Ctrl+i CR-i as a way to step "forward"?

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there a way to have 
`noremap <tab> <c-w><c-w>` in vim without ruining Ctrl+i  for traversing forward in files that were previously open, but "stepped back from" with Ctrl+o?

I learned today that apparently "Ctrl+i and tab are considered the same in vimrc?

Is it possible to separate behaviour in Ctrl+i from pressing tab?
Feels like I'm missing sth obvious somewhere.

//vim nooub

Comment: Other thoughts are - why are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

Answer (score 2):

`<C-i>` and `<Tab>` are indistinguishable for Vim and for most if not all terminal emulators. Therefore, mapping anything to `<Tab>` also maps it to `<C-i>` and conversely.

Note that you shouldn't use `noremap`. Use `nnoremap` for non-recursive normal mode mappings, `inoremap` for non-recursive insert mode mappings, etc.